# Problem with tinyMCE autoresize plugin with Boostrap 4.2.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, autoresize

When using tinyMCE with Bootstrap version 4.2.1, the plugin autoresize does not change the height of the tinyMCE div.

There is a css conflict that can be solved with adding 1 line of css after boostrap css and tinyMCE css :

```
<style>
    .form-control.tinyMCE{height: unset;}
</style>
```